# How to make a polyline with two-sided arrows show two colors

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, c#, features, line

I am very new to ArcGis development and so bear with me if I asked a silly question. I am using ArcGis 10.2 on C#.

I have two features (A and B) on the map. I need to place two arrowed lines - one from A to B (pointing B), and one from B to A (pointing A). Both sets are expected to show different colors, which will convey different meanings to the users.

Currently, I have a `PolylineClass` for the line and `ArrowMarkerSymbolClass` for the arrow, which are eventually packed into `LineElementClass` before adding to one of the map layers. This is done twice - once from A to B and another time for B to A. The problem is that the two sets of arrowed lines are **overlapping**. Because the ability to see the colors of the two sets of arrowed lines is the most important function here, I need to change how it is implemented.

I have two ways in mind, but I have no idea if it is achievable.

1. Draw two separate arrowed lines side-by-side. I totally have no idea how this is possible because the two lines share the same two coordinate points on the map.
2. Draw half of each arrowed line to a color.

Current Implementation:

[image: Current Implementation]

Method 1:

[image: Method 1]

Method 2:

[image: Method 2]

So, is there any way I can achieve either #1 or #2?

### Update

Posting some codes so that it's easier to understand what I'm doing.

```
    private void DrawArrowedLine(Place from, Place to, RgbColor color)
    {
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PolylineClass polyLine = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PolylineClass();
        polyLine.SpatialReference = MapHelper.GetSpatialReference();

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point fromPoint = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point();
        fromPoint.SpatialReference = MapHelper.GetSpatialReference();
        fromPoint.X = from.Location.Longitude;
        fromPoint.Y = from.Location.Latitude;

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point toPoint = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point();
        toPoint.SpatialReference = MapHelper.GetSpatialReference();
        toPoint.X = to.Location.Longitude;
        toPoint.Y = to.Location.Latitude;

        polyLine.AddPoint(fromPoint);
        polyLine.AddPoint(toPoint);

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ArrowMarkerSymbolClass arrow = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ArrowMarkerSymbolClass();
        arrow.Color = color;
        arrow.Size = 12;
        arrow.Length = 12;
        arrow.Width = 8;

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.CartographicLineSymbolClass cartoLineSym = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.CartographicLineSymbolClass();
        cartoLineSym.Color = color;
        cartoLineSym.Width = 3;
                   
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.SimpleLineDecorationElementClass lineDecElem = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.SimpleLineDecorationElementClass();
        lineDecElem.AddPosition(1);
        lineDecElem.MarkerSymbol = arrow;

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.LineDecorationClass lineDec = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.LineDecorationClass();
        lineDec.AddElement(lineDecElem);

        cartoLineSym.LineDecoration = lineDec;

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.LineElementClass lineElem = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.LineElementClass();
        lineElem.Symbol = cartoLineSym;
        lineElem.Geometry = polyLine;
        lineElem.Name = CommsLinkName;
        lineElem.SpatialReference = MapHelper.GetSpatialReference();

        // ArrowLayer is ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.CompositeGraphicsLayerClass
        MapHelper.GetArrowLayer().AddElement(lineElem, 0);
    }
```

Comment: I'd go method 1 by using an offset. I take it you're drawing this line with ArcObjects, have a look at IMultiLayerLineSymbol http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w00000205000000 or if drawing between StartDrawing and FinishDrawing phases you could copy/flip the line for calls to DrawPolyLine... please show some of your code that implements the symbology and drawing so we can understand where you're up to.. there are several ways you could be drawing and the advice is different for each way.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson updated.

Comment: Definitely the MultiLayerLineSymbol, create two LineSymbol implementing ILineProperties http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w000001pr000000 and set the offset away from the actual line to give some 'breathing space' between the layers, flipping the second layer to orient the line in the reverse direction then set lineElem.Symbol (ILineSymbol) YourMultiLayerLineSymbol; (ILineSymbol implements MultiLayerLineSymbol http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w000001q3000000)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It suddenly struck me that I can simply set `Offset` on the `CartographicLineSymbolClass` instance, since I'm calling the method twice with the from/to objects swapped.

Comment: That works too, as you're using MapElements you can do it that way, this approach also works with IDisplay.DrawPolyline but when creating a renderer to apply to a feature layer you only get one pass (draw phase) and so the MultiLayer symbols are the way to go. Glad that I could be of some help. Now would be a good time to answer your own question with the updated code to assist future users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I am calling the `DrawArrowedLine()` method twice - once from A to B, and another time from B to A, so I can simply set an `Offset` value.

```
cartoLineSym.Offset = 5;
```